# Finger scanner in node-webkit application

Tags: windows, node.js, desktop, node-webkit

I am just starting my NodeJS way and do not understand all power of it.

I want to develop node-webkit desktop application (windows), and I know that I will have the task to integrate any **fingerprint verification device** to it.

I found one interesting thing named node addons.
If I will have C++ sdk for fingerprint verifyer is it possible to develop some wrapper to use it in Node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. You will likely also need [nw-gyp](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Build-native-modules-with-nw-gyp).